# middleware Codename One and mobile apps

Tags: android, mobile, cross-platform, middleware, codenameone

I want to ask about the middleware Codename One :
what it really is ?
what are advantages and drawbacks of using it, when developping a mobile application (Android or iPhone)  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of Codename One.

This answer might help you understand a bit about the internals of Codename One: [How does Codename One work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639766/how-codename-one-works)

In general [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) is several things:

1. Developer API abstracting platform differences in GUI, file system, networking and more.
2. A set of tools for development integrated with an IDE plugin (GUI builder, device simulator etc.).
3. A cloud build server that converts the bytecode to a native application and an optional runtime cloud allowing you to use features such as push, cloud storage etc.

The advantages are pretty simple: Write your application once and have it work on everything using pretty standard Java tools: Eclipse/NetBeans. You don't need a Mac to build for iOS, you don't need a Windows machine to build for Windows Phone/RIM. The platform is huge and comprehensive.

The drawbacks are:

1. Not suitable for elaborate games, e.g. fps etc. The framework was designed from the start as an application framework and so were the related tools.
2. While its possible to build without the cloud build server it isn't trivial and eliminates a lot of the advantages of the platform (you will need a Mac etc.). So you need the cloud build server and then you have a monthly quota of builds, to get more builds you need to pay.
3. Some features of the devices aren't supported. You can access native code if what you need isn't there but obviously that's not ideal.