# How does Codename One work for device specific features?

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

Maybe I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around it. I kind of understand how it works from the research I've done, especially this question: [How does Codename One work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639766/how-codename-one-works)

But what if I want to intercept incoming texts in Android? How does that affect the iOS app? If I want to use Vimeo's API to upload videos (I have an Android app that does it), will I have to get the source code and add that separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incoming texts can't be intercepted in iOS as far as I know.

For Android you can use intents to intercept incoming texts but that's a bit of a pain you would need to write Android native code for that which you can do with [native interfaces](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) in Codename One.

I'm not very familiar with the Vimeo API but if its a REST API then you can pretty much map to it with Codename One's networking API using `NetworkManager`, `ConnectionRequest` etc.